# Windows 10 Minecraft updated 16.2.1 causes flashing screen on HP 15 Notebook

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I had no issues with playing my Windows 10 (bedrock edition) Minecraft on 16.1, until I updated to 16.2.  I updated the game and started the game, which went to the red Mojang screen and then the following white screen, however, from there it went to a flashing red/black screen.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the game, did not help.  I have a HP 15 Notebook with an Intel HD graphics.  I could not update the graphics driver because it's a custom build.  My computer is updated with the latest Windows update.  I updated today to the latest Minecraft update.  But that did not help. I had no issues playing the game before the 16.2 update.  In fact I was playing Minecraft when I noticed that there was a new update.  Since then I have not been able to play.  Please help.

Comment: First, update your game. Or do you mean `1.16.200`?

Comment: Yes, I have actually updated it to the newest update, I believe it was 1.16.201, but the game still will not work for me.  I have put a lot of money and time into this game and would be willing to purchase a new computer just so I can play again but would prefer not to have to do that.